# What is the recommended firmware for a TP-LINK TL-WR841ND?

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, firmware

What would be the best firmware for this cheap router?

The default firmware is okay, but I have the itch to tweak so I flashed it with DD-WRT. I would like to hear some pros and cons regarding different firmwares and why they work best on this device.

Comment: The best firmware version usually be the last one. Take a look at TP-Link website and get the newsest one.

Comment: @DiogoRocha I think he's really asking about aftermarket third party open source firmware distros like DD-WRT, OpenWrt, Tomato, etc.